# Flickity AsNavFor producing error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')"

Tags: javascript, laravel, slider, carousel, flickity

i'm using flickity as the instructions, but got this error warning in the console
anybody know how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Here is the current bundle package

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-as-nav-for@3/as-nav-for.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
```

i'm using flickity AsNavFor but it shown an error in the console, how do i get rid or solve of it?

typeof Require
[image]

Comment: How have you installed each of `flickity` and `flickity-as-nav-for`. Are you using a bundler like webpack, or a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Can you put a debug point on this line and see if Flickity is defined? If it isn't that means it has not yet initialized or not loaded. Also if you are using CDN, check if the scripts are loading correctly.

Comment: @adsy currently using as a bundler, look at the updated question

Comment: @VikasArora I'm using a cdn, and yes it loaded correctly..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is what fixed it for me.

Swap out: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-as-nav-for@3/as-nav-for.js"></script>`

with: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-as-nav-for@2/as-nav-for.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your `script` tags:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-as-nav-for@3/as-nav-for.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, but i've tried that before and still produce the same error in the console :')

Comment: In the dev tools can you do `typeof Require` and report back the response?

Comment: i post the screenshot above